# Soldering devices to the USB ports

Tags: usb, usb-hub

In [this project](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-and-Arduino-Laptop/) the maker of the project desolders and removes two of the USB ports on the Pi and solders on a USB Hub to the pads at the bottom.

I'd like to solder devices to the USB pads in the same way and would like to know if I can do the same while leaving the USB ports in place.

Will the USB ports still be usable this way? Does doing this effectively add a new USB port?

Comment: `Will the USB ports still be usable this way?` yes, but `Does doing this effectively add a new USB port?` no. It's either / or. You can only use one device per port (unless you connect a hub, of course)

Comment: If I had a device soldered on to the pad and accidentally connected another one to the USB port, what would happen? Will the second device simply not be activated or will I lose the first device and switch to the second one?

Comment: Or you loose both? TBH: I don't know, could be any of several scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solder a device directly on the PCB without removing the USB ports.

It will not give you extra USB ports. If you connect 2 devices to the same port the most likely outcome is that neither device will function properly.